# Changing store view (language) to the default store view, it goes back to homepage

Tags: magento2, language

I have "Add to store code to url" enabled, I have two store views with different name and url of the category for each store view, now I'm in category page: example.com/en/category, when I switch language the system will redirect me properly to example.com/it/categoria but if I go back to the default language, it will redirect me to the homepage....